# Using throng, SIGINT listener do not prevent from exit node

Tags: node.js, multithreading

This question is about the node module [throng](https://github.com/hunterloftis/throng).
As described at Node Documentation, node should prevent from exit, when listener is defined on SIGINT or/and SIGTERM. But `throng` will always exit.

> If one of these signals has a listener installed, its default behavior
>   will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events

## How to reproduce

Use the default example on GitHub and comment out the process.exit line, node will still exit the process.

```
const throng = require('./lib/throng');

throng({
  workers: 1,
  master: startMaster,
  start: startWorker
});

// This will only be called once 
function startMaster() {
  console.log(`Started master`);
}

// This will be called four times 
function startWorker()(id) {
  console.log(`Started worker ${ id }`);

  process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log(`Worker ${ id } exiting...`);
    console.log('(cleanup would happen here)');
    //process.exit();
  });
}
```

Tested on macOS 10.12.3, NodeJS 7.7.3 and throng 4.0.0

Testing the `startWorker` method without `throng` will work. The process don't stop. So this must be a problem on `throng`.

Has anyone already made such experience with `throng` and can explain the behavior to me?

Comment: use pm2 instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly an error because the developer specifies it exactly as in its module description and examples.
Nevertheless, I think it could not work properly from the beginning, because when the master process is closed, all child processes will be automatically terminated. Waiting for the end of the child processe not to have been provided.
The developer seems to have already recognized this. There is gint 2 pull request that deals with this problem.